# Get the total value of the users vote in Rate module

Tags: rating, users

I  have added rate module to enable voting on comments and content. But I want to get the total no. of vote got by a users comment and give badges based on that. I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do custom coding to achieve above functionality. Assigning User Badges on Cron run will be a good option. Below steps will help you to solve the problem.

- Create a custom module
- Implement hook_cron
- Get list of users who doesn't have comment votes badge.
- Get above list of users comment score using custom query
- Loop through results and check for your condition to assign badge
- Assign badge using user-badges API. Look into user badges module where it assigns badge to user to figure out logic to assign badge!

Hope it helps :-)